# ¿Cómo oculto id en url en php?

Tags: php, url

Tengo un problema muy leve,  por estética necesito ocultar el id de la imagen cuando de observa en la url del navegador Ejemplo:

```
eaxample.com/imagen?id=1
```

Entonces, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para generar un id de 8 caracteres con letras mayúsculas, minúsculas y números?

```
eaxample.com/imagen?id=Arq24K70
```

Para luego mejorar la url como:

```
eaxample.com/imagen/Arq24K70
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar con esto, muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Intenté utilizar la función md5(), pero es muy larga.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la encriptacion basica de php base64 encode para codificar la id y base64 decode para obtener el dato cifrado

```
<?='<td href="eaxample.com/imagen?id='.base64_encode($id).'>Ver imagen</td>'?>
```